# complex analysis exercise

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this exercise:

The only thing I need help to is explaining why I can assume that z is real? I've tried assuming z is complex, and trying to rewrite it to a equivalent expression, but it didn't work. Do you guys see why we can assume that z is real?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The quantities $$|z|, \quad |w|,\quad \bar z\,w,\quad |z-w|$$
all remain unchanged when $z$ and $w$ are replaced by $e^{i\alpha} z$ and $e^{i\alpha} w$.

Answer (score 1):

The open unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$ has *rotational symmetry*. Rotation is an isometry.

The same is true for the unit circle $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$.

Let $\mathrm{R}_{\theta} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an anti-clockwise rotation about the origin through an angle of $\theta$ radians.
$$\begin{eqnarray*} |z| < 1 &\iff& \mathrm{R}_{\theta}(z) < 1\\ \\
|z| = 1 &\iff& \mathrm{R}_{\theta}(z) = 1
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand this. So if you start with z with $|z|<1$, then you rotate it $\theta$ radians?, how does this help?

Comment: @user119615 Rotate until $z$ is on the real axis. For example, if $z=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}$ then you can rotate $\frac{\pi}{2}$-radians anti-clockwise and find yourself at $z=-\frac{1}{2}$.